# PrimeNG Turbotable master selection does not update on page change

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I am working on a PrimeNG turbotable with checkbox to select all items on a page. I am running into an issue when page changes the master selection checkbox does not update.

[image]

The source code is available on plnkr, https://next.plnkr.co/edit/YFIfVpER0FFaoiQU?preview

Answer (score 1):

I had to override 2 methods, `toggleRowsWithCheckbox` and `updateCheckedState` of Turbotable to achieve this. If somebody is interested in how I did it or the code, it is here below. This goes in the constructor of my TurboTable wrapper.

```
TableHeaderCheckbox.prototype.updateCheckedState = function () {
  const currentRows = _.map(this.dt.value, this.dt.dataKey);
  const selectedRows = _.map(this.dt.selection, this.dt.dataKey);
  this.rowsPerPageValue = this.dt.rows;
  const commonRows = _.intersection(currentRows, selectedRows);
  return commonRows.length === currentRows.length;
};

Table.prototype.toggleRowsWithCheckbox = function (event, check) {
  let _selection;
  if (!check) {
    _selection = this.value.slice();
    _.each(_selection, (row) => {
      const match = {}; match[this.dataKey] = row[this.dataKey];
      _.remove(this._selection, match);
    });
  } else {
    _selection = check ? this.filteredValue ? this.filteredValue.slice() : this.value.slice() : [];
    _.each(this._selection, (row) => {
      const match = {}; match[this.dataKey] = row[this.dataKey];
      _.remove(_selection, match);
    });
    this._selection = this._selection.concat(_selection);
  }
```

I have used "lodash" for some of the operations, like `intersection`, `map`, `remove`, `each` etc.